# How to split flv file by size using FFmpeg or mencoder or smth else?

Tags: linux, bash, ffmpeg, flv, mencoder

I need to split an flv file into chunks of the known size on linux server. For example my original file is 9Mb and the chunk size is 4Mb. So I should get 3 parts - 4Mb, 4Mb and 1 Mb.

Seems that FFmpeg can split only by time.

Mencoder can start by time (-ss TIME) and finish by size ( -endpos SIZE MB). But if start second of the first chunk is obviously 0, then how can I get start second for next chunks?

Do you have any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does the result files need to be legal flv?

Comment: It should be playable but not necessarily flv.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

calculate ~time (sec) of every block & use -ss X -t X+avg_block_time for split video

Answer (score 1):

There is a commandline utility which does just that: http://mpgtx.sourceforge.net/

```
mpgtx -3 movie.mpg -b mysplit
```

will split the movie into 3 chunks with the names mysplit-1.mpg, mysplit-2.mpg, mysplit-3.mpg

That said, I seem to have trouble with the audio when I use this - but I don't know if you'd have that problem too.