# Splitting .flv file in Java OR php

Tags: java, ffmpeg, flv

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to split flv file by size using FFmpeg or mencoder or smth else?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1045430/how-to-split-flv-file-by-size-using-ffmpeg-or-mencoder-or-smth-else)

I have a big .flv of about 10 hours I want to split it in 10 mins. Can I do this in Java or PHP using ffmpeg, if yes can you please direct me to a specific documentation where I can achieve this.

```
public class splitFlv {
 public static void main(String[] args) {  
             try {  
                 System.out.println("Splitting started");
                 Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ffmpeg –i 1000.flv -acodec libfaac -ss 00:00:00 -t 00:10:00 -ar 22050 -ab 32 -f flv 1010.flv");
                 System.out.println("Splitting ended");
                 BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(  
                                     new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));  
                 String line = null;  
                 while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {  
                     System.out.println(line);  
            }  
             } catch (IOException e) {  
                 e.printStackTrace();  
             }  
        }
```

}

I wrote this code but its not working

Answer (score 0):

FFMPEG can split videos, it has to be invoked from command line.

ffmpeg –i video.flv -acodec libfaac -ss 00:00:00 -t 00:03:00 -ar 22050 -ab 32 -f flv video1.flv

- acodec is audio codec that is libfacc
- ss is starting time
- t is ending time
- ar audio sample rate 22050 Hz
- ab audio bit rate that is 32 kilobits per second
- f flv is output file format that is flv.
- S is dimensions of output file.

In PHP/ Java, you can to that with "exec/RunTime.getRunTime().exec" to execute this command.